# TypeError: 'PollingException' object is not iterable, python error when posting a request

Tags: python

I try to POST a python object to my endpoint

```
 def test_atg_polling_exception(self):
        status=200
        jsonEncoder = CustomJSONEncoder()      
        a= PollingException('System.OutOfMemoryException','System.OutOfMemoryException','System.OutOfMemoryException','2009-02-15T00:00:00Z')
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
        response = requests.post("http://localhost:5000/PollingEngineExceptions",data=a,headers=headers)
        print response.status_code
        assert status not in response.status_code
```

But getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ratha/projects/test711/ATGWS/tests/TestEndpoint.py", line 46, in test_atg_polling_exception
    response = requests.post("http://localhost:5000/PollingEngineExceptions",data=a,headers=headers)
  File "/Users/ratha/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ratha/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ratha/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/ratha/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ratha/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 460, in send
    for i in request.body:
TypeError: 'ATGPollingException' object is not iterable
```

What Im doing wrong?
My endpoint accepts `PollingException` object as request parameter

Comment: Please include the _complete_ error message.

Comment: `assert status not in response.status_code` but `status = 200`. I read that as in you expect this to fail.

Comment: @roganjosh Not really, I expect 200 status code, but getting 500 internal error[error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Comment: @roganjosh what im trying to say is assert is not an issue, issue caused with my POST request!

Comment: @DYZ I edited my question with full error stack. DO you see any issue with my POST call?

Comment: According to documentation, `data` must be a dictionary, bytes, or file-like object. You pass an exception instead.

Comment: @DYZ, I have created a Exception Object class.(it is a model class) Im trying to post that PollingException object. Can't I? I have asked anothe r question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48632977/how-to-use-requests-library-to-post-a-python-object-in-flask

Comment: A class cannot be posted. You must serialize it first (say, with pickle).

Comment: @DyZ thanks that works